HTML Form Post URL
Ok so I have a HTML form which is using javascript to display an image thats uploaded here is my HTML code
<form action="/inc/sendtochan.php" method="post">
              <label for="fname">Title:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="title" value="" size="64"><br>
              <label for="discription">Enter content description:</label><br>
              <textarea name="discription" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea><br>
              <label for="link">Link to content:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="lcontent" name="lcontent" value="" size="64"><br>
              <label for="link">Select Image:</label><br>
              <div class="profile-picture">
              <h1 class="upload-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </h1>
              <input
                class="file-uploader"
                type="file"
                onchange="upload()"
                accept="image/*"
                name ="imageurl"
              />
              </div><br><br>
              <input type="submit" name="submitcontent" value="Send Content to Channel">
            </form>

The javascript involved which displays a box, which then changes to a preview of the image selected
function upload() {
  const fileUploadInput = document.querySelector('.file-uploader');

  if (!fileUploadInput.value) {
    return;
  }

  const image = fileUploadInput.files[0];

  if (!image.type.includes('image')) {
    return alert('Sorry Only images are allowed!');
  }

  if (image.size > 10_000_000) {
    return alert('Maximum upload size is 10MB!');
  }
  
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(image);

  fileReader.onload = (fileReaderEvent) => {
    const profilePicture = document.querySelector('.profile-picture');
    profilePicture.style.backgroundImage = `url(${fileReaderEvent.target.result})`;
    
  }
}

Everything works perfect and the image displays, now to the php from the post request, what I am trying to get is the url of the image to be posted, in my /inc/sendtochan.php I am reading the data from the post request with
$imageurl = trim($_POST['imageurl']);

But when I echo this, it basically is just returning the image name, what I want the post form to actually post is the image url. Any help would be appricated.
Thank you
I can get the image url to display straight away when its selected by adding this to the javascript
return alert(`url(${fileReaderEvent.target.result})`);


So I just need to actually have that url sent with the post request, now the image name

You mean the FORM action URL? Or the resulting URL of the image, after you've moved it to some folder on your server? You can read the actual server url from the $_SERVER array. Beyond that, the URL could be anything, including an URL to a script which delivers the image.

I am thinking maybe I need to alter my JavaScript to save the image to a server folder? I assume at the moment my java code just saves the image temp to display it on my page, but yes I want that temp url where the image gets stored to be sent with my post action, at the moment it's posting the img name, but I need the url of the image

Since you are using a <form> already, you can easily add a hidden field to the POST request:
<form ...>
  <input type="hidden" name="imageurlonly" value="">
</form>

and write into it with your JavaScript function
function upload() {
  // ...
  fileReader.onload = (fileReaderEvent) => {
    const profilePicture = document.querySelector('.profile-picture');
    profilePicture.style.backgroundImage = `url(${fileReaderEvent.target.result})`;
    document.querySelector('[name="imageurlonly"]').value = fileReaderEvent.target.result;
  }
}

then you can access it in PHP with
$imageurl = $_POST['imageurlonly'];


LEGEND!!! This has done exactly what I needed it to do, thank you so much!

The content of the file being uploaded in the POST request is not in the $_POST array, it is in the $_FILES array. w3schools.com has a good tutorial on this: PHP File Upload.
The upload() function that you created is just fine. Then, when you click the submit button the form should just do an ordinary POST request (MIME type multipart/form-data) without you having to do anything else. And then you can find the file in the $_FILES array using PHP.
